# How to reconstruct array from $_POST['image'][0] to $_POST[0]['image']

Tags: php

If I have two array,

```
$_POST['image'][0]
$_POST['caption'][0]
```

how to reconstruct to

```
$info[0]['image']
$info[0]['caption']
```

Is there any function to do it?

Comment: I don't think you should be doing this. The predefined variable `$_POST` is [reserved for passing form data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware What about reconstruct it to an array, not modifying $_POST?

Comment: I think you mean 'restructure'? Yes, assigning `$_POST` content to an array can certainly be done. Use the `=` [assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) for this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware What I want to say is transforming $_POST['image'][0] to $info[0]['image'], is there any function to do it automatically?

Comment: As I said, use the assignment operator: `$info[0]['image'] = $_POST['image'][0];`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so what if there are more attributes like $_POST['caption'][0] and $_POST['author'][0]? I want a more automatic way.

Comment: You can use a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to walk through the `$_POST` array and do the assignments. Try it. If you cannot work it out ask a new question, but pay attention to this: 1. Explain what you want to do. 2. Show the whole array you want to restructure. 3. Show the output you want. 4. Show your attempt.

Comment: You don't need to ask a new question, add your attempted code to this question. But we're not going to write it for you, you're expected to [try to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)